# How to define a Typescript type using generics

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Let's say I have the following interface defining an object:

```
interface ExampleInterface {
    a: string:
    b: number;
    c: AsyncFunction<boolean>
}
```

where AsyncFunction is defined by:

```
type AsyncFunction<T> = () => Promise<T>;
```

This currently works well if the function supplied to c: has no parameters, but causes a TS2322 compilation error if the function has any parameters.

The idea is that `<T>` is used to define the return type within the Promise of the function. The function may or may not need its own parameters, but it must provide the specified T return type within a Promise.

My question is, is there a way to modify the type definition so that any function with zero or any number of parameters of any fashion can be used in **c**:?

I've tried to understand infer but all of my attempts to use it (and it may not be what I'm looking for) have ended up with **c**: having an (any) return type which is not what I want. I've also tried using the following with no success.

```
type AsyncFunction<T> = (...args: any[]) => Promise<T>;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're going to need a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of this problem for us to be able to help you. Try reproducing it in the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) if possible. If the problem does not manifest in playground, give the minimum to reproduce it with tsc/vscode.

Answer (score 1):

Your example "tried the following with no success works perfectly":

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIA84FsAOAbCASXGniWQG8AoZW5OALmQGcwpQBzAGhroCMmIAK5Y+0HnWQImAQWYBPEAgBiQpWGAB7EAB4+mzQTggAfFQC+VKmHk4UcxSrUIN2nQBUTyALzIAFAB0QXBQHMxMxvIA2gC6AJQ+XgAKUJpYwMwQHmZUCNqsyJCsTBjY+EQksIgovtSSjMgAREVgjRL8TACMAEwAzO200vQKSv4J3l5sQhAWVnkgBQAWEHh4mkwpaRlZ+oYQxl6+LQEIfo3MaRBtyAAMXE1QxgAmadex940hHCIQ4MyNcSAA)

Comment: Perhaps I'm having one of those days. In TS playground, you're right it is working. I'm using Visual Studio. When passing a function with no parameters, I can set c as `c: foo` but if foo has parameters I have to use `c: () => foo(1, "x")`. I've never come across this, and to be honest, I'm not sure why it's like that.

Comment: Actually to go even further, if I set it with `c: () => foo(1, "x")`, I don't even need the `...args: any[]` in the type definition.

Comment: @JonBellamy What is the type of `foo`?

Comment: It's a function. `async function foo(a: number, ...): Promise<boolean>{}`

Comment: I've just realised why it's not working and I'm being a complete idiot - perhaps I should take a break. Now the question is here, I'll put up the answer for anyone else coming across it. Sorry for wasting your time, I've given you the upvote and if I could just delete the question with a reason of 'OP being stupid' I would! Thank you for helping me come to my senses!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Rubydesic making me walk through everything to provide more details, I realised I was being an idiot.

The reason it wouldn't compile had nothing to do with the type definition - that didn't actually need changing.

The issue was that with no parameters, I was simply passing the method name into c:

```
async function foo(): Promise<boolean> {
// Body omitted
}

const x: ExampleInterface = {
a: 'a',
b: 0,
c: foo
}
```

Of course, this worked, but when the method had parameters I was then passing those in (which because of the need for brackets would be attempting to execute it, not passing it in - the part I failed to realise after a long day - talk about missing the obvious). I was doing:

```
async function bar(a: number): Promise<boolean> {
// Body omitted
}

const x: ExampleInterface = {
a: 'a',
b: 0,
c: bar(0)
}
```

When I should have been doing

```
async function bar(a: number): Promise<boolean> {
// Body omitted
}

const x: ExampleInterface = {
a: 'a',
b: 0,
c: () => bar(0)
}
```

Answer posted as a painful reminder to take a break every so often. In 10 years, I don't think I've ever been quite so blind to the problem!